# Reading multiple files one by one

Tags: c++, file-io

I am almost done with my project, but I still have one small thing that needs to be done...I need to run the entire program for each file in the directory.  There are about 200 files in total. Below is the main class of the program that needs to run. I'm thinking I will put the entire thing in a do-while loop and run it until there are no more .dat files in the directory, but I'm not sure if that will work. Obviously, I'd like to replace the hard-coded file names with variables...I'm just not sure how to do that, either.  Please let me know if you need clarification. I've been working on this project for a while and I'm getting kind of brain-numb. Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit** My test directory is on a Windows machine, but it will be uploaded to a linux machine at school.

```
  int main() {

    NearestNeighbor face;
    //string path = "C:\Users\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CSCE350";
    //string searchPattern = "*dat";
   // string fullSearchPath = path + searchPattern;


    /*TEMPLATE DATA*/

    /***********************************************************************************/
    fstream templateData;
    double data = 0.0;

    templateData.open("003_template.dat", std::ios::in);
    //check that the file is opened
    if (!templateData.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Template: Nooooooo!\n";
        exit(0);
    }


    /*************************************************************************************/
    //fill the templateVector with the values from templateData
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > templateVector;
    std::string line;

    while (getline(templateData, line, '\n'))
        templateVector.push_back(face.splitData(line));

    //testing the contents of the templateVector
    //  cout << "TemplateVector: ";
    //   for (unsigned i = 0u; i != templateVector.size(); ++i) {
    //           
    //    std::cout << "Index[" << i << "] ";
    //    for(double value : templateVector[i])
    //        std::cout << value << " ";
    //    std::cout << "\n";
    //  }


    /*QUERY DATA*/
    /************************************************************************************/
    std::ifstream inFile("003_AU01_query.dat", std::ios::in);
    std::vector<double> queryVector;

    double pixel = 0.0;

    // Check that the file opened
    if (!inFile.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Query: Nooooooo!\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    // fill the queryVector with the query data

    while (inFile >> pixel) {
        queryVector.push_back(pixel);
    }
    inFile.close();

    //   testing the content of the query vector
    //   for (unsigned i =0u; i < pixels.size(); i++){
    //       std::cout << "Index["<< i << "] " << pixels[i];
    //   }   
    //    std::cout << "\n";

    /*OUTPUT SCALAR PRODUCT*/
    /****************************************************************************************/
    vector<double> theList;
/*break out each of the vectors from the templateVector and compute the scalar product*/
    for (auto& vec : templateVector) {
        int i;
        cout << "\nscalar_product: Index[" << i << "] " << face.scalar_product(vec, queryVector);
        theList.push_back(face.scalar_product(vec, queryVector));//fill theList vector with the computations
        i++;
        std::cout << "\n";

    }
    //make sure that the sorted products are output with their original index numbers
    vector<pair<int, double> > sorted;
    sorted.reserve(theList.size());
    for(size_t i = 0.00; i != theList.size(); i++){
        sorted.push_back(make_pair(theList[i], i));
    }
   //sort the scalar products and print out the 10 closest neighbors
    face.quickSort(sorted);
    cout << "\nVector after sort:\n";
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << "idx: " << sorted[i].second << " " << "val: " << sorted[i].first << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not write a small script (e.g., bash) that provides the file name as argument to your code. So, the script can iterate through all files in the directory and run your code for each of them.

Comment: Because I haven't got a clue how to do that. That sounds like that would be much more efficient. I'll look into it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A solution in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in `ls`
do
    ./program $file
done
```

Of course you'd have to modify your `main` function to take an argument to pass to the `fstream` constructor:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        // some error handling code
    }

    ifstream templateData(argv[1]);
    if (!templateData)
    {
        // more error handling
    }

    // process the file
}
```

Comment: Just noticed from your `path` variable that you're on Windows (C:\etc). Not sure how useful this is for you now. Something similar should be possible... shouldn't it? No experience with windows shell scripting (hint: migrate! ;-)). The changes to `main` are still valid though.

Comment: Well, it's going to be on a linux machine. I just have to upload it to the school's server. :)

Comment: So, would I do a similar line for queryData like what you have for templateData?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I missed the second file. Just allow for 2 parameters to be passed over the command-line (`if (argc != 3)`).

Comment: So..stupid question..what do you mean by "modify your main function to take an argument to pass to the fstream"?

Comment: In your question, your `main` doesn't take any parameters. My snippet adds this so you can pass the filenames over the CLI. If you're not familiar with this concept, look at this:http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html, or Google for "C command line parameters"

Answer (score 0):

From your code it is windows.

This code will print all the *.dat file names in your folder:

Instead of printing do whatever you like.

first You'll need to include:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Now to the code:

```
    const wstring dir = L"C:\\Users\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CSCE350";
    const wstring ext = L"dat";  
    wstring findstr = dir;
    findstr += L"\\*.";
    findstr += ext;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(findstr.c_str(),&ffd);
    do{
        if(!(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)){
           wstring path = dir;
           path += L"\\";
           path += ffd.cFileName;
           wcout<< path<<endl;
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
    FindClose(hFind);
```

**EDIT:**
On linux you can give your program a parameter path/to/dir/*.dat and you'll get the parameters trough argv, maybe its the better solution.

But if you insist to do it with code it is like this:

includes:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
```

Now the code:

```
    const string dirname = "path/to/dir";
    const string ext = ".dat";
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *de;
    if((dir  = opendir(dirname.c_str())) == NULL) {
       //error... check errno and so on
       cerr<<"Error..."<<endl;
    }else{
       while ((de = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {  
          //you can use stat to check if is is file or dir...
          string filename(de->d_name);
          if(ext = filename.substr(filename.size()-ext.size())){
             cout<<dirname<<"/"<<filename<<endl;
          }
       }
       closedir(dp);
    }
```

Good luck

Comment: Thank you for this, but it will be on a linux machine. Can I do something similar?

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't do it like this. Keep your program modular, handling one file at a time, and let the rest be handled by the shell. If you don't, you'll end up with hard-coded, non-portable lines of code. It will bite you in the *** when you need to use it under different circumstances.